# Increasing memory size in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I am running android application in eclipse. Its very slow(showing total heap size as 230). I am having 8GB RAM, so i want to increase the heap size to make my application works faster. Can anyone advice me?

Comment: this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6748432/java-heap-space-out-of-memory/13682852

Answer (score 3):

Open eclipse.ini file in your Eclipse root and change the values -Xms and -Xmx to the smallest and the largest amount of memory you'd want your Eclipse to use, in your case it would be OK to use these settings:

-Xms1024m
-Xmx2048m

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Go to eclipse installation folder and open `eclipse.ini` and replace the last line with
`-Xmx1024m` .Now 1gb RAM will be reserved for eclipse. You can give any size as you want.