# Play framework 2.1 outofmemory exception

Tags: java

I encounter this problem, any one tell me how to control this？

```
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[RuntimeException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space]]
    at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:287) ~[play.play_2.10-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:381) [play.play_2.10-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$play$core$server$netty$PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$handle$1$1.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:143) [play.play_2.10-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$play$core$server$netty$PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$handle$1$1.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:139) [play.play_2.10-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
    at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) [play.play_2.10-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
    at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) [play.play_2.10-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
    at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Promise.scala:104) [play.play_2.10-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.0.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.0.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [na:1.6.0_35]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [na:1.6.0_35]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [na:1.6.0_35]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at play.libs.F$Promise$6.apply(F.java:401) ~[play.play_2.10-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.liftedTree2$1(Future.scala:253) ~[org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.0.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:249) ~[org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.0.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:249) ~[org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.0.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:29) ~[org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.0.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.liftedTree1$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:67) ~[com.typesafe.akka.akka-actor_2.10-2.1.0.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.processBatch$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:66) ~[com.typesafe.akka.akka-actor_2.10-2.1.0.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:82) ~[com.typesafe.akka.akka-actor_2.10-2.1.0.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:59) ~[com.typesafe.akka.akka-actor_2.10-2.1.0.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:59) ~[com.typesafe.akka.akka-actor_2.10-2.1.0.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72) ~[org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.0.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:58) ~[com.typesafe.akka.akka-actor_2.10-2.1.0.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:137) ~[com.typesafe.akka.akka-actor_2.10-2.1.0.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1417) ~[org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.0.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:262) ~[org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.0.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:975) ~[org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.0.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1478) ~[org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.0.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104) ~[org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.0.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6748432/2764279) may help you

Comment: @Ankit Lamba  thanks, I'll see the post